# Is it permissible to work for an organisation that supports LGBTQ?

Tags: halal-haram

I’m a doctor interested in reproductive health and rights, I work for several international and regional organisations that advocate for women’s rights. I advocate for maternal and child health and girls education and against violence against women and harmful practices such as female genital mutilation.

The problem is international organisations add the LGBTQ agenda to this bundle of sexual and reproductive health; I personally do not support the LGBTQ community or the access to abortion (for non Islamic reasons such as convenience), and I do not promote it. My question is, is it halal to work for and take money from these organisations given that I stick firmly to the areas I mentioned above (such as maternal health)?